# How to increase LinkedIn X-Ray search result count?

Tags: linkedin

I am using [LinkedIn X-Ray Search](http://www.google.com/custom?q=nodejs&num=100&cof=CX:X-Ray-LinkedIn%3B&cx=009462381166450434430:ecyvn9zudgu&prmd=ivns&ei=S1GJVeGBOM67uASev4GQAQ&start=0&sa=N) to get information.

Problem: Maximum number of results is 1000. I had tried start=1001 it is not working.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: Why do you believe `start=1001` _should_ work?